# How can I read user input from form in angularjs and create a yaml?

Tags: angularjs

I am new to angularjs. I have a nested form using ng-repeat in each form so that user should be able to enter something like a list of lists. How can I access the user input value and store/read it through backend code so that I can create a yaml of specific pattern and process it later on.

Comment: Welcome @Arun ! Please [edit] your question and paste your code; what have you tried? Read [mcve] on how to ask to get best answers.

Comment: Try to `POST` the data using `$http.post` to send the form data to BACKEND